# Using RIA Services directly within an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am starting a new project which will need a ASP.NET MVC 2.0 website, a Silverlight section and a Windows Phone 7 UI.

My plan was to use WCF RIA Services to create a set of services which would be used in all different UI projects. With the Silverlight project I would use the standard tool integration, the Windows Phone looks like it may have to be WCF Services exposed by the RIA Domain Services, but I'm not sure about the ASP.NET MVC website.

My initial thoughts I would simple reference the class library containing the Domain Services and use them directly. Could this be considered a viable approach to using RIA Domain Services in a ASP.NET MVC website?

Kind Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I know a long time has passed since this question was asked, but since I had to make such a decision, I might as well document it for the benefit of others.

I work in an environment where lots of legacy and new apps co-exist, with the legacy apps being phased out. So we've had to build interoperability between everything from MS Access, to web service end points in C#, VB, Web Forms, MVC 3, even Flex, Reporting Services...the list goes on.

One of the biggest pain points in a multiple-client scenario is the maintenance of interoperability over time. As data, requirements and delivery mechanisms change, keeping things smooth ends up taking a lot of resources.

My approach has been to create one and only one mechanism for reading a given source of data by defining 1) a model, 2) a serialization/deserialization layer and 3) a service layer. All projects that need to use XY_Data must use the XY_Service to get XY_Objects via the XY_Serializer. Direct db calls or stored procs, etc are allowed in the XY_Application. This allows me to drop in replacement DLLs (versioned) with bug fixes and upgrades without restarting anything. I hardly ever do a full publish.

So yes, what you're suggesting will work. I would recommend only that you rigorously enforce the single-source-of-truth and DRY policies both in your data *and* your APIs.